# Getting JSON Object from a line provided

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file, from the Github API. Because this is from a search, I want to get the specific JSON Object (that wraps around the search hit indices) that was identified during the search. I am provided the indices of the search hits.
I am using JS.

Comment: [You need to add more detail to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter in javascript to search and get the particular object.